# How do I code a Makefile that can tell the difference between Intel OS X and Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, makefile, gnu-make

How do I write a conditional into a GNU `make` Makefile, which discerns the architecture (Intel OS X vs Linux, in this case) so that I can set flags appropriately, without requiring the end user to specify the Makefile when running `make -f`?

**EDIT**

I should specify that I get a makefile error from an `ifeq` statement that contains a shell command, if this conditional is placed outside a target:

`'commands commence before first target. Stop.'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to check the output of one of the `uname` variants, and then choose different actions withing the `makefile` depending on that.

Run `man uname` for details.

In terms of how you use it from GNU make, you can get the information into a variable from the `shell` function and then use `ifeq` on that variable:

```
platform=$(shell uname -o)

ifeq ($(platform),Cygwin)

defrule:
    echo I am running in Cygwin.

else

defrule:
    echo I am running elsewhere.

endif
```

Comment: `uname -o` isn't actually valid on OS X. `uname -s` may be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

`uname` is your friend.

```
$ uname -o
GNU/Linux
```